# Can i use if-statement within a constructor to control the range of values its parameters take without resulting to raising an exception?

Tags: java, constructor, priority-queue

i want to write a constructor that takes a int parameter called capacity (i am trying to create a priority queue class) and i need to lock the capacity parameter in positive-only values.Can i use an if satement within the constructor?

```
public PriorityQueue(int capacity){
    this.capacity=capacity;
    int[] array=new int[capacity];
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can! Throw an exception in case you receive < 1.

Comment: Yes, you can - but it's important to understand that you can try this yourself before asking on Stack Overflow.

Comment: thank you i will try it.Can i recommend u somehow??

Comment: i didnt think about raising an exception because i am new at java sr

Answer (score 3):

If you want to *force* the user of this class to use positive values only, the only way is an exception. Otherwise the object would be constructed, regardless.

```
public PriorityQueue(int capacity){
    if(capacity < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative value \"capacity\"");
    this.capacity=capacity;
    int[] array=new int[capacity];
}
```